# Working with WebRTC on IOS

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, webrtc

I am happy that I got Video Chat working with WebRTC on iOS by following the tutorial here:
http://ninjanetic.com/how-to-get-started-with-webrtc-and-ios-without-wasting-10-hours-of-your-life/

But, I am not able to understand how is it Peer to Peer Video Chat when I am connecting to the appspot server (Google App Engine using Channel). Is it possible to remove this appspot. I have my own client verification system. So, I am pretty sure to maintain the proper authentication of who is going to connect to whom.

Answer (score 0):

The GAE channel is used for signaling. Signaling is not part of webrtc and you can use any signaling method you like.

```
"Exchange of information via signaling must have completed successfully 
before peer-to-peer streaming can begin"
```

You can find more information [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/infrastructure/) and [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/)